# Finding probability from random number generator

Tags: python, probability

I am working on a personal problem that requires me to find the probability that the sum of three randomly chosen real numbers between 0 and 1 is greater than 1. I have tried writing the code in python, but I think there's an error:

```
import random

a = random.random()
b = random.random()
c = random.random()

n = int(input("Enter a range: "))
for i in range(n):
  wanted = 0
  if (a + b + c > 1):
    wanted += 1
  else:
    wanted += 0
print("The ratio is " + str(wanted/n))
```

Can you please point out the problems with my code or direct me otherwise?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I also just learned that 1 is not included in ```random.random()```. Can you please suggest how I may include it?

Comment: Forgive me for asking, but why not? Choosing a = 1, b = 0 and c = 0.001 seems perfectly valid...

Comment: actually depending on your application it might make sense. I removed my comment

Comment: *"I think there's an error"* - Why?

Comment: I've fixed my error now. The downvotes are a bit uninspiring, but I'll keep getting better at this.

Answer (score 0):

To me seems like two issues :

1. each time you want to create a new set of random numbers, so they should go inside the loop
2. and `wanted=0` should be before loop, you are resting it to 0 each time

```
import random

n = int(input("Enter a range: "))
wanted = 0
for _ in range(n):
  a = random.random()
  b = random.random()
  c = random.random()
  if a + b + c > 1:
    wanted += 1
  
print(f"The ratio is {wanted/ n:.2%}")
```